# Checking for optional protocol methods in Swift gives error?

Tags: swift, protocols, option-type

After reading the Apple docs on optional protocol requirements it says you can use optional chaining to check for the implementation. I tried this out and I keep getting an error. It seems like this is no longer a valid way of doing this and I am trying to find out if there is a new way to do this now.

Here is a example so you can see the error: http://swiftstub.com/743693493/ 
Here is my code:

```
@objc protocol Bearable {
    func growl()
    optional func cough() -> String //Apparently bears cough when they are scared. 
}

@objc class Bear:Bearable {
    var name = "Black Bear"
    func growl() {
        println("Growllll!!!")
    }
}

@objc class Forest {
    var bear:Bear?
    func scareBears() {
        if let cough = bear?.cough?() {
            println(cough)      
        } else {
            println("bear was scared")  
        }
    }
}
```

I get the error: `error: 'Bear' does not have a member named 'cough'
if let cough = bear?.cough?() {`

Comment: It works if you define `bear` as `var bear: Bearable?`

Comment: @MikeS You are absolutely correct.

Comment: @MikeS can you just write that as an answer so I can choose that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The error you're getting makes sense because Swift can know at compile time that `Bear` doesn't implement `cough()` (whereas Objective-C wouldn't necessarily be able to know that).

To make your code compile, you need to define `bear` using the `Bearable` protocol instead of the `Bear` class.

```
var bear: Bearable?
```

Which is probably what you'd want anyway. Otherwise, there's not much point in creating that protocol.

Comment: Excellent answer thank you! You are a gentleman and a scholar.